# Split SQL Columns by Regex Substr

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I need to split this SQL Columns using Regex and extracted the last part (LN1_DEF_DEPT).
Can someone help me?

LDS^1^LN1_DEF_DEPT

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Char `^` is delimiter ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correct understood, you need this

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR('LDS^1^LN1_DEF_DEPT',  '[^\^]+$') from dual
```

Comment: It Worked! Thanks so much!